# ASP.NET Core 7.0 Razor Pages - Get POST request body

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I've just started using ASP.NET Core 7.0 Razor Pages. I've previously been using Node.js with Express to setup endpoints on my website. I want to do the same thing in ASP.NET but I can't find any examples on how to do this in Razor Pages, no matter where I look.

So here's what I want to do.

I want to set up and endpoint at `/test`. If I send a HTTP `POST` request to that URL (e.g. by using Postman), I want to capture the request body and process it on the backend.

For example if I was in Node.js and sent in two params in the body of the request (username & password), I would do this to read the data:

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
   const { username, password } = req.body;
   console.log('username is: ', username);
   console.log('password is: ', password);
});
```

I want to accomplish exactly the same thing but in ASP.NET Core. So what have I done so far? First I created a new Razor page inside my `Pages` folder. I named it `Test.cshtml`. Inside that file I removed everything except `@model TestModel` because I do not want this to be a page on the site that people can visit, it should only be used for `POST` requests - nothing else.

Then inside its C# file (`Test.cshtml.cs`) I have this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace MyWebsite.Pages
{
    public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received a post request.");
        }
    }
}
```

The first thing I'm trying to do is see if I can capture that I've sent a `POST` request. For now I'm ignoring what data (body) I've sent. I just want to see something that says "I received your post request."

So I'm going inside Postman, and I send a post request at the URL. But nothing shows up in the console. Is this not how you capture a POST request? And how would I capture its body?

This is not from any form on the page. This is just an endpoint (`/test`) which should be handling various kinds of POST requests. And then I should be able to process the data, e.g. insert it to a database or something.

Comment: Razor Pages are intended to be used for generating HTML-based UI. The equivalent to your Node endpoints in ASP.NET Core is minimal request handlers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/route-handlers?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple Post endpoint you need something like this:

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        return Content("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

But if you call this from Postman it will return 400 because it's missing the anti forgery token, but it will work if you add a button or a form inside your razor page.

If you are just exploring and testing stuff, you can replace this line in your `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
```

with this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(o =>
{
    o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

And it will work via Postman too. More info about [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

If you want to access the body of the request the best approach is creating a class with the schema of the request like this:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPost([FromBody] Request request)
{
    return Content("Hello world!");
}

public class Request
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

You can call this endpoint with a request like this:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:5057/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "username": "MyUser",
    "Password": "MyPass"
}'
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I access the actual body of the request? Let's say I'm sending it in as JSON.

Comment: @Olote I've edited my answer to include the JSON in request body

Answer (score 0):

Do what @ctyar said but also it sounds like you’ve removed the `@page` directive from the cshtml file? I believe you’re going to need this to route requests to the page in the first place. It must be the first thing in the cshtml file.

#### Getting the body

Getting the body of the request depends on the content-type. If it’s a form content-type, the framework will have already put everything into `Request.Form` as individual KeyValuePairs, for example. You can work with that directly or use model binding to make ASP.NET do some validation for you.

**Forms**
Reading individual values from `Request.Form`:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    var myValue = Request.Form["myKey"];
}
```

Receiving known named values as typed arguments. The types must of course match, `string` will always work, other types like `int` may give you their `default` value if the input is invalid, others may throw `InvalidOperationException`.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string username, string password, int age)
{
    //form data is automatically mapped to the arguments for you by name
}
```

**Json**
If you want to receive a JSON string coming in with content-type `application/json`, you can read it directly from the body stream:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    var myObject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<dynamic>(Request.Body);
}
```

For this you’ll need a class that matches the JSON or you can use `dynamic`.

**Raw body**
The request body is exposed as a stream, so you can use a `StreamReader` to capture it. This will not be available if the Framework has already handled it automatically (like if it’s a form).

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    string body = await new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code examples on how to work with that data, e.g. a form data?

Comment: @Olote Sure, I’ve added some examples

Comment: If the request is of type 'Content-Type: application/json', do you still have access to `Request.Forms`?

Comment: @JamesPoulose Hi, no, just accessing the Form property will throw `System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type`. That makes sense, because a form is a list of keys and values, and a Json string may contain all kinds of nested things.